Dataset isnt shown in RStudio version 4.4.1 after using function View(“name of the dataset”)
My friends are using the exact same function and the dataset pops out immediately but this is what it’s shown on my laptop. Specifically, it pops out another slide and a sentence: name of the dataset, type character [1] and value “name of the dataset”. I cant find anyway to view the dataset.My tutor opened it once but I forgot. How can I view the dataset? I tried the utils:: function but it’s not working. Thanks so much guys
Ive tried utils:: function

v4.4.1 is the version of R, not RStudio.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried it without using the quotation marks?
View(dataset)
Instead of the current View("dataset").
